# jenkins using default jnlp agent for every first time build and thereafter using defined agent label

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

Team,

I have set below logic in my jenkins groovy script to use agent based on params.

```
def buildAgent() {
    agent = 'artifacts'
    if (params.Cuda) {
        agent =  'artifacts-gpu'
    }
    if (params.'Image Targets'.contains('scrubber')) {
        agent = 'artifacts-scrubber'
    }
    return agent
}
```

what i am observing is whenever I run the pipeline for first time, build is running on JNLP agent and when i run again it runs on the agents defined in my function `buildAgent`

is there a caveat in my logic? or is there a different problem in my pipeline? like do i need to set a default agent? i thought it is set by `agent = 'artifacts'`

I am calling like this

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        label buildAgent()
    }
```